# Erro de SQL ao tentar Fazer um UPDATE com o PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
public function AlterarDoador(ClasseDoador $AlterarDoador) {
        try {
            $pdo = conexao::getInstance();
            $sql = "UPDATE doador SET nome=?,cpf=?,datadenascimento=?"
                    . "sexo=?,endereco=?,complemento=?,bairro=?,cidade=?"
                    . "estado=?,cep=?,email=?,senha=?,telefone=?,perfil=?,datacadastro=? "
                    . "WHERE iddoador = " . $AlterarDoador->getIddoador() . ";";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $AlterarDoador->getNome());
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $AlterarDoador->getCpf());
            $stmt->bindValue(3, $AlterarDoador->getDatadenascimento());
            $stmt->bindValue(4, $AlterarDoador->getSexo());
            $stmt->bindValue(5, $AlterarDoador->getEndereco());
            $stmt->bindValue(6, $AlterarDoador->getComplemento());
            $stmt->bindValue(7, $AlterarDoador->getBairro());
            $stmt->bindValue(8, $AlterarDoador->getCidade());
            $stmt->bindValue(9, $AlterarDoador->getEstado());
            $stmt->bindValue(10, $AlterarDoador->getCep());
            $stmt->bindValue(11, $AlterarDoador->getEmail());
            $stmt->bindValue(12, $AlterarDoador->getSenha());
            $stmt->bindValue(13, $AlterarDoador->getTelefone());
            $stmt->bindValue(14, $AlterarDoador->getPerfil());
            $stmt->bindValue(15, $AlterarDoador->getDatacadastro());            
            return $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gabriel bem vim ao stackoverflow, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja como criar perguntas, poste o erro que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao site. No título de sua pergunta, você afirma que houve um erro de SQL. Qual o erro?

Comment: Tem erro de sintaxe, faltam `,` em alguns campos olhe as quebras de linhas

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: foi esse o erro

Answer (score 3):

Gabriel, primeiro vamos imaginar como seria um `UPDATE`, independente de usar o `PHP` para executá-lo. Seria algo do tipo:

```
UPDATE nome_da_tabela
   SET campo1 = valor_campo1,
       campo2 = valor_campo2,
       campoN = valor_campoN
 WHERE condicao_aqui;
```

Você informa o **nome da tabela**, e no `SET` pode colocar **1 ou mais campos** com seus **respectivos valores** para a atualização, **separados por vírgula**. E por último, com o `WHERE`, coloca as **condições para filtrar os registros**, caso contrário toda a tabela será atualizada.

Agora vamos ver esse seu código:

```
$sql = "UPDATE doador SET nome=?,cpf=?,datadenascimento=?"
                    . "sexo=?,endereco=?,complemento=?,bairro=?,cidade=?"
                    . "estado=?,cep=?,email=?,senha=?,telefone=?,perfil=?,datacadastro=? "
                    . "WHERE iddoador = " . $AlterarDoador->getIddoador() . ";";
```

Já podemos notar que na mudança das linhas você esqueceu de separar os campos por vírgula. O correto seria assim:

```
$sql = "UPDATE doador SET nome=?,cpf=?,datadenascimento=?,"
                    . "sexo=?,endereco=?,complemento=?,bairro=?,cidade=?,"
                    . "estado=?,cep=?,email=?,senha=?,telefone=?,perfil=?,datacadastro=?, "
                    . "WHERE iddoador = " . $AlterarDoador->getIddoador() . ";";
```

Se depois dessa correção continuar com erro, verifique se informou **valores para todos os parâmetros**, nas linhas `$stmt->bindValue`.

Se persistir o erro, altere sua pergunta informando o mesmo.